# Indeterministic behavior of actors in concurrency example

Tags: scala, actor

I've recently wanted to give Scala a try and I started by reading book 'Programming Scala' by O'Reilly. I've tried example from this page:
http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch01.html#ATasteOfConcurrency
and I get different results each time I run the shapes-actor-script - sometimes only first line of output is produced, sometimes the whole output, sometimes no output at all. I am using scala 2.7.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Actors in Scala fail to process messages? (example in O'Reilly's Programming Scala)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809553/can-actors-in-scala-fail-to-process-messages-example-in-oreillys-programming)

Comment: While both questions approach the problem in a different manner, they are both related to the observed output of the same example from the same book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Can Actors in Scala fail to process messages? (example in O'Reilly's Programming Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809553/can-actors-in-scala-fail-to-process-messages-example-in-oreillys-programming/4811053#4811053)