# Strange/Random behavior mixing Actors and DaemonActors

Tags: scala, actor

This may be related to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809553/can-actors-in-scala-fail-to-process-messages-example-in-oreillys-programming), but I am not so sure.......

I have an Scala/Actor-based subsystem that uses 3 cooperating actors to do some work. Each of the Actors is actually a DaemonActor. External messages are sent into a primary Actor, and occasionally messages are sent from a secondary Actor to the primary, asking it to do stuff with the data it collected from the external messages.

I wrote a test-driver Scala program that starts up the subsystem in question, and uses a DaemonActor to send messages to the subsystem (that is to the primary Actor).

It turns out that messages sent into the primary Actor were processed by the primary Actor, but messages sent from the secondary subsystem Actor to the Primary Actor were not processed.

I discovered that if I made the Actor in the **test-driver program** a non-Deamon Actor, and not a DaemonActor, everything worked as expected. This was 100% deterministic in that when the external test-driver used an Actor, the subsystem always behaved. When the external test-driver used a DaemonActor, the subsystem always mis-behaved. No other changes were made to the code when switching between Actors and DaemonActors.

The make things even stranger, when I made an expanded test driver that used 2 Actors to send 2 different types of messages to the subsystem, I had to make one of the test driver's actor a DaemonActor or the subsystem receiving messages mis-behaved.

Seems pretty random :-)

One caveat to note: The test driver actors actually call methods on a subsystem class which "translates" the method call into a message send to the primary subsystem actor. This is for compatibility with Java code.

I tried a number of different ways to tell if messages where being processed. However I did it I needed some info from the program, while it was running, and I devolved to printing stuff out. Thus my reference to the question thread about printing and flushing buffers.  The only thing that seemed to affect behaviour was Actor vs. DaemonActor.

I could send out code, but it would be kind of a lot.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that you haven't started the actors?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is it. The only change I make between the broken code and the working code is to change parent classes of my test program Actors from "DaemonActor" to "Actor." Literally, I just delete the 6 "Daemon" characters. And re-compile/run. If I was not starting the actors, then I would think I have issues with either parent class.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the workflow around the DaemonActor, and are you using Scala 2.7 or 2.8?  If you post your code on a gist or pastebin-type system, I'm sure many of us would be happy to look at it. :)

In 2.8, regular actors prevent the runtime from terminating while they active; DaemonActors, as the name implies, do not.  If you are simply sending the DaemonActor one or more messages and then the program ends, it may never even get to the point of sending messages to the other Actors.

Comment: Wajiii, thanks for the reply! After a couple of weeks of neglect, I got back to my program and discovered the source of the problem, although not why the behaviour was so "random." I had pulled a piece of code in from elsewhere in our system, never suspecting that it would do a Thread.sleep(someMillis).