# Basic Scala Actors: examples from books not "acting" at all

Tags: scala, actor

I'm very new to Scala, and too rusty in Java to consider myself anything else than a complete newbie. So I'm taking easy steps to learn it.

When looking at actors, I tried a few things, but faced many NoClassDefFound errors. Ultimately, I decided to take a book example and build on top of it instead of debugging my first attempt. Surprise: the book examples don't work as expected!

Here's the example from O'Reilly's Programming Scala:

```
import scala.actors.Actor

class Redford extends Actor {
  def act() {
    println("A lot of what acting is, is paying attention.")
  }
}

val robert = new Redford
robert.start
```

It's supposed, when executed, to print the Redford quote.  However when I launch it, nothing happens, I get back to command line:

```
D:\prog\scala-2.8.1.final\pierric>scala testactors.scala

D:\prog\scala-2.8.1.final\pierric>
```

Another example comes from Seven Programming Languages in Seven Weeks. It's like this (I only changed the strings out of laziness):

```
import scala.actors._
import scala.actors.Actor._

case object Poke;
case object Feed;

class Kid() extends Actor {
    def act() {
        loop {
            react {
                case Poke => {
                    println("Ow")
                    println("Quit it")
                }
                case Feed => {
                    println("gurgle")
                    println("burp")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var bart = new Kid().start
var lisa = new Kid().start
println("starting")
bart ! Poke
lisa ! Poke
bart ! Feed
lisa ! Feed
```

This time it's supposed to return a randomly ordered sequence of "ow quit it" and "gurgle burp". However, when I run it:

```
D:\prog\scala-2.8.1.final\pierric>scala testkids.scala
starting

D:\prog\scala-2.8.1.final\pierric>
```

Now, another amusing thing. If I add a simple println line at the beginning of my act method:

```
class Kid() extends Actor {
    def act() {
        println("Kid initializing")
        loop {
            react {
                ...
```

Then I get most of the times:

```
D:\prog\scala-2.8.1.final\pierric>scala testkids.scala
starting
Kid initializing
Kid initializing

D:\prog\scala-2.8.1.final\pierric>
```

But sometimes also:

```
starting
Kid initializing
Kid initializing
scala.actors.Actor$$anon$1@5a9de6: caught java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main$$anon$1$Fee
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main$$anon$1$Feed$
            at Main$$anon$1.Main$$anon$$Feed(testkids.scala:5)
            at Main$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(testkids.scala:31)
            at scala.actors.Actor$$anon$1.act(Actor.scala:135)
            at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:222)
            at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:222)
            at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:36)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$AdaptedRunnable.exec(ForkJoinPool.java:6
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.ja
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:32
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main$$anon$1$Feed$
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

So here I am, clueless... as those are examples "out of the book", actually out of 2 books! and don't seem to work. I've tried on 2 different machines, which in all likeliness have different JVM's. In both cases I've run scala 2.8.1.final. One machine runs Windows XP 32-bit, the other one Windows 7 64-bit. I didn't find anything related to this kind of issue by googling...

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed a light on this!

Pierric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because scala script running exits hard as soon as they are finished in the main thread. That works very bad in a setting with multiple threads (see [Can Actors in Scala fail to process messages? (example in O'Reilly's Programming Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809553/can-actors-in-scala-fail-to-process-messages-example-in-oreillys-programming)). If instead you start scala and load the scripts like this:

```
# scala
scala> :load testactors.scala
Loading testactors.scala...
import scala.actors.Actor
defined class Redford
robert: Redford = Redford@29e07d3e
res0: scala.actors.Actor = Redford@29e07d3e

scala> A lot of what acting is, is paying attention.
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it works in this way. Note that I would really like to be able to build Scala scripts, just like I'm used to Ruby scripts. Even if Ruby is more appropriate for small hacks, it's a good way to learn a language by practice...

Comment: From your link, it seems synchronized and wait are keywords that can help. I've tried adding a synchronized wait to one of the kids in the kids example, and it worked. However, requiring to wait for the 2 kids caused the script to run fully but to hang at the end. As I don't understand what is really happening here, I guess I need further info on this synchronized stuff (seems to be a Java concept, but I don't know it as I've never really used Java after learning the basics many years ago). Do you think I'll find explanations on this concept by reading Programming Scala, or another Scala book?

Comment: In addition to wait for the other threads you must also ask them to stop their processing. If not they will just keep on waiting for new messages. You can do that by running the actors exit-method on an exit-message.

Comment: Thanks thoredge. Actually I also modified the Kids example to call the exit method upon receiving the Feed message (after printing the "dialog" lines). When I wait on an actor, it normally has already received the Feed message, and should be calling the exit method. However that only works when I wait for one of them... well, anyway, I guess that now that I got the base examples working, I'll study a little more and hopefully I'll understand that soon enough!